# Send messages from salesforce to facebook using facebook toolkit

Tags: facebook

I am using to **Force.com Facebook toolkit** to send message to facebook.
I am able to send message using **java script** in facebook, below is my java script code

```
<script> 
          function closewindow(){
              window.close();
          }
          FB.init({appId: '{!id}', status: true, cookie: true});
          function postToFeed() {
            var obj = {
              method: 'send',
              to: '{!fbuserid}', 
              link: '{!$CurrentPage.URL}',
              description: 'Testing'
            };
            function callback(response) {
                if (response['post_id']) {
                    var postId = response['post_id'].split('_')[1];
                    document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 
                        "Posted to your wall. "+
                        "<a href=\"https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?"+
                        "id={!me.id}&v=wall&story_fbid="+postId+"\">View your post</a>";
                }
            }
            FB.ui(obj, callback);
          }
  </script>
```

The message which is received in facebook comes with a error message as shown in picture below.
[image: message received in facebook look like]

Please help to remove error or send message using graph api

Answer (score 1):

[This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13026723/33905) suggests that the problem might be that Sandbox mode is checked for your Facebook app. You might do better asking these questions on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) with the Facebook tag there.

You could also take a look through the [Google results on "This attachment may have been removed or the person who shared it may not have permission to share it with you"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22This%20attachment%20may%20have%20been%20removed%20or%20the%20person%20who%20shared%20it%20may%20not%20have%20permission%20to%20share%20it%20with%20you%22&oq=%22This%20attachment%20may%20have%20been%20removed%20or%20the%20person%20who%20shared%20it%20may%20not%20have%20permission%20to%20share%20it%20with%20you%22).